# If $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{V} \neq 0$ at only one point, will this prevent us from saying that $\vec{V}=\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{U}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields, divergence-operator, curl

**This question has an answer in the language of high level mathematics. Can somebody explain this in the language of vector calculus.**

**Part I:** Let us consider Cartesian coordinate system with origin $O$ and axes $x,y,z$. Let:

$$r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$

$$\text{and }\vec{V}=0\ (\hat{i})
+\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z} \left( \dfrac{1}{r}  \right) (\hat{j})
-\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} \left( \dfrac{1}{r}  \right) (\hat{k})$$

It is obvious that $\dfrac{1}{r}$ is defined everywhere except at the origin.

Now let us take the divergence of $\vec{V}$:

$$\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{V}=0$$

Since $\dfrac{1}{r}$ is not defined at the origin, $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{V}=0$ is true everywhere except at the origin.

**Since $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{V} \neq 0$ at a point $P (0,0,0)$, will this prevent us from concluding $\vec{V}=\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{U}$ at points other than $P$? Why? Why not?**

**Part II: If $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{V} \neq 0$ at points on a one dimensional arbitrary curve in space, will this prevent us from concluding $\vec{V}=\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{U}$ at other points not on the curve? Why? Why not?**

> **NOTE - For both Part I and Part II:**
>
> If **(Why/Why not)** is beyond the scope of vector (multivariable) calculus, just reply as **yes/no**. However please try your best to explain **(Why/Why not)** in the language of vector (multivariable) calculus.

**SEMI ANSWER: Please point out the limitations**

I have stumbled upon a *derivation* in the language of elementary vector calculus. Please point out if there are any limitations in my derivation. In the context of advanced mathematics (de Rham cohomology or Poincare lemma), it *seems to me* that there are limitations.

**Derivation:**

**To prove:** At all points where $\vec{B}$ is defined (whatever be the domain of $\vec{B}$), if $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{B}=0$, then $\vec{B}=\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{A}$

**Proof:**

At all points where $\vec{B}$ is defined (whatever be the domain of $\vec{B}$):
\begin{align}
\vec{B} &= B_x\ (\hat{i}) + B_y\ (\hat{j}) + B_z\ (\hat{k})\\
&= B_x\ (\hat{i}) + B_y\ (\hat{j}) + \int^{(x,y,z)}_{(x,y,\infty)}
\dfrac{\partial B_z}{\partial z}\ dz\ (\hat{k})\\
&= B_x\ (\hat{i}) + B_y\ (\hat{j}) - \int^{(x,y,z)}_{(x,y,\infty)}
\left(  \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{B} - \dfrac{\partial B_z}{\partial z}\   \right) dz\ (\hat{k})\\
&\text{{Since $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{B}=0$}}\\
&= B_x\ (\hat{i}) + B_y\ (\hat{j}) - \int^{(x,y,z)}_{(x,y,\infty)}
\left(   \dfrac{\partial B_x}{\partial x} + \dfrac{\partial B_y}{\partial y}\   \right) dz\ (\hat{k})\\
&= B_x\ (\hat{i}) + B_y\ (\hat{j})\
+ \left[
 \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}
\left(- \int^{(x,y,z)}_{(x,y,\infty)}B_x\ dz \right) 
-\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}
\left(  \int^{(x,y,z)}_{(x,y,\infty)}B_y\ dz \right)
\right]
(\hat{k})\\
&\text{{By changing the order of integration and differentiation}}\\
\end{align}

> At all points where $\vec{B}$ is defined (whatever be the domain of $\vec{B}$), let's define:
>
> $\displaystyle \vec{A}=\int^{(x,y,z)}_{(x,y,\infty)}B_y\ dz\ (\hat{i}) - \int^{(x,y,z)}_{(x,y,\infty)}B_x\ dz\ (\hat{j}) + 0\ (\hat{k}) + \vec{\nabla}f$
>
> where $f$ is an arbitrary function of $(x,y,z)$

Therefore at all points where $\vec{B}$ is defined (whatever be the domain of $\vec{B}$):

\begin{align}
\vec{B} &= \left(
\dfrac{\partial A_z}{\partial y}-\dfrac{\partial A_y}{\partial z}
\right) (\hat{i})
+\left(
\dfrac{\partial A_x}{\partial z}-\dfrac{\partial A_z}{\partial x}
\right) (\hat{j})
+\left(
\dfrac{\partial A_y}{\partial x}-\dfrac{\partial A_x}{\partial y}
\right) (\hat{k})\\
&= \vec{\nabla} \times \vec{A}
\end{align}

Comment: Does the statement say something about how it is defined $\vec U$?

Comment: $\vec{U} \rightarrow \vec{U} +\vec{\nabla}f$ is the vector whose curl gives $\vec{V}$......$f$ is an arbitrary function of $x,y,z$

Comment: The origin isn't in the domain of $\bf V$, so it doesn't even make sense to ask whether $\nabla \cdot {\bf V} = 0$. It's true that $\nabla \cdot {\bf V} = 0$ everywhere on the domain of $V$.

Comment: How do we know that the origin isn't in the domain of $\bf {V}$?

Comment: Because the quantity $\frac{1}{r}$ that appears in the definition of $\bf V$ isn't defined at the origin.

Comment: @Travis: So do you mean the theorem $(\text{if } \nabla \cdot {\bf V} = 0 \text{ then,} \bf V=\nabla \times \bf U)$ is true at all points where $\bf V$ is defined?

Comment: (1) I was just addressing the point about whether $\nabla \cdot {\bf V} = 0$ fails---namely, it only makes sense to ask whether it fails at a point of its domain, and in this case $0$ is not in that domain. (2) That's not actually a theorem as written---you need additional hypotheses. (Having trivial second de Rham cohomology of the domain is sufficient, but for the domain $\Bbb R^3 - \{0\}$ of $\bf V$ the second de Rham cohomoly is not trivial. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Rham_cohomology#Punctured_Euclidean_space )

Comment: (In any case, it *is* true here that there is a vector field $\bf U$ for which ${\bf V} = \nabla \times {\bf U}$.)

Answer (score 10):

You seem to know that a divergence free field $\vec V$ can be regarded as curl of some other field: There is a field $\vec U$ such that $\vec V={\rm curl}(\vec U)$. This is a consequence of the so-called [Poincaré Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms#Poincar%C3%A9_lemma).

But there is a catch: The Poincaré Lemma  guarantees the existence of such a [*vector potential*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_potential) $\vec U$ only if the domain of $\vec V$ is, e.g., a ball or star shaped. For your field $\vec V$ this is not the case. Therefore we only can say the following: Each point ${\bf p}$ in the punctured space $\dot{\mathbb R}^3:={\mathbb R}^3\setminus\{{\bf 0}\}$ is the center of an open ball $B_r({\bf p})\subset \dot{\mathbb R}^3$ such that within $B_r({\bf p})$ the field $\vec V$ can be written in the form $\vec V={\rm curl}(\vec U)$ for some $\vec U$ defined in $B_r({\bf p})$ only. These local fields $\vec U$ are not uniquely determined, and it is not at all sure whether the implied "integration constants" can be chosen in a coherent way such that we obtain a single field $\vec U_*$, which then would be  defined on all of $\dot{\mathbb R}^3$.

Of course, it could be that "by coincidence" the $\vec V$ in your example possesses a global vector potential $\vec U_*$ nevertheless: not by the Poincaré Lemma per se, but because a certain integrability condition (say, the flux of $\vec V$ across a sphere around ${\bf 0}$ should be $=0$) is fulfilled. Consider as an analogue the functions $z\mapsto{1\over z}$ and $z\mapsto{1\over z^2}$ in the punctured complex plane $\dot{\mathbb C}$. Both have local primitives. But one of them does not have a global primitive in $\dot{\mathbb C}$, the other does, the reason being that $$\int_{\partial D}{1\over z}\>dz=2\pi i\ne0\>, \qquad \int_{\partial D}{1\over z^2}\>dz=0\ .$$

**Update:** I suggest you look at the entry [Helmholtz decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition) in Wikipedia and apply Helmholtz' theorem to a large ball minus a tiny ball around the origin.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Please can you explain this in a way so that a physics graduate student can understand.

Comment: You asked the question at MSE. There is some deep mathematics involved here, called the *De Rham complex*, see here:   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Rham_cohomology . I had hoped to explain what is relevant in your example in such a way that a physics student can understand.

Comment: "The flux of $\vec{V}$ across a sphere around $\bf {0}$ should be $=0$"...Can you show how? Would it be true for other volumes than sphere....

Comment: Full answer. What is the meaning of $\dot{\Bbb R}^3$?

Comment: I was deliberately cloudy here, since I don't know  for sure what is necessary and sufficient. Ask your physics professor. Note that "usually" people just consider the full space ${\mathbb R}^3$ or balls.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: "$\vec{V}$ in your example possesses a global vector potential.......because a certain integrability condition (say, the flux of $\vec{V}$  across a sphere around $\bf{0}$ should be $=0$) is fulfilled." If flux over an infinitesimal closed surface around the origin is zero, i.e. $\unicode{x222F} \vec{V} \cdot \vec{dS}=0$ , will it mean that at origin $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{V}=\dfrac{d\ \unicode{x222F} \vec{V} \cdot \vec{dS}}{dV}=0$ even though $V$ is not defined at the origin?

Comment: @Joe: I didn't say your $\vec V$ has a vector potential. I told you everything I can take responsibility for, given my knowledge of these things. See also my update.

Comment: @Joe The first chapter of the David Griffiths' (great) book "Introduction to Electrodynamics" is dedicated to vector analysis in a way that is useful and meaningful to the physicist. I recommend it highly.

Answer (score 0):

It is a consequence of the Kelvin-Stokes theorem:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin%E2%80%93Stokes_theorem

If you take a potential $U=\frac{1}{r}$ with associated "electric field" $E:=\nabla U$ then you know that the flux of $E$ through a unit sphere $\Sigma$ centered around $(0,0,0)$ is 1.

However by Kelvin-Stokes if you could write $E=curl(B)$ for a certain vector field $B$ then the flux of $E$ through $\Sigma$ would be equal to 0 since $\Sigma$ is closed surface.