# How to show $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{P}=0$ over the whole domain of ${\mathbb R}^3$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-fields, divergence-operator

If in ${\mathbb R}^3$,

$r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\text{ and }\vec{P}=
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z} \left( \dfrac{1}{r}  \right) (\hat{j})
-\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} \left( \dfrac{1}{r}  \right) (\hat{k})$

how can we show that $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{P}=0$ over the whole domain of ${\mathbb R}^3$?

> **Edit in response to the answer**
>
> It is said in the answer that "The problem is that the field $f=1/r$ itself is not even defined at the origin, so its derivatives are not going to be defined either".
>
> With this information, is it correct to say that $\vec{P}=\nabla \times \vec{A}$ everywhere except the origin. **Why? Why not?**

Comment: What have you done so far? What is the coordinate expression for $P$? Given a vector field $F$, how do you compute $\nabla\cdot F$?

Comment: It can be very easily seen that $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{P}=0$ everywhere except origin. How shall we show $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{P}=0$ at origin? This is what I mean by "how can we show that $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{P}=0$ over the whole domain of ${\mathbb R}^3$?"

Comment: We had the same question by the same OP yesterday:   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3015453/if-vec-nabla-cdot-vecv-neq-0-at-only-one-point-will-this-prevent-us-f/3015663#3015663

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the field $f = 1/r$ itself is not even defined at the origin, so its derivatives are not going to be defined either. That being said you could define the field

$$
f_a = \frac{1}{r + a} \tag{1}
$$

for some constant $a > 0$, and then calculate ${\bf P}_a$ as

$$
{\bf P}_a = \frac{\partial}{\partial z}f_a ~\hat{y} - \frac{\partial}{\partial y}f_a ~\hat{z} \tag{2}
$$

so that

$$
\nabla \cdot {\bf P}_a = \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial y\partial z}f_a -  \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial z\partial y}f_a \tag{3}
$$

since $f_a$ has continuous derivatives, you can switch the order, therefore

$$
\nabla \cdot {\bf P}_a = 0 \tag{4}
$$

Now take the limit

$$
\nabla \cdot {\bf P} = \lim_{a\to 0}\nabla \cdot {\bf P}_a = 0
$$

Comment: "The problem is that the field $f=1/r$ itself is not even defined at the origin, so its derivatives are not going to be defined either". With this information, is it correct to say that $\vec{P}=\nabla \times \vec{A}$ everywhere except the origin.